# Multiple content types in a single library - sharing columns

Tags: infopath, content-type, forms-services

I have built a simple expense claims feature into a sharepoint site using infopath. All works fine, but we wish to expand this to handle multiple types of claim, each having it's own form, travel expenses, holiday allowance etc.
Each claim type is a separate site content type . I had hoped to store and display these in a single 'Claims' library, split/ordered by claim type. But the way it is set up at the moment, even the common fields like claimant, amount, from/to dates etc will be separate per content type.
Is there any way to get multiple infopath forms to promote their properties to a shared column? 
I could just have a different view per claim type, but it would be neater if I could group them together.

Regards,

Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns already exist as normal (UI-created) columns when you set up your promoted fields, InfoPath will use them without making them sealed. You should be able to point multiple forms to the same fields that way.

Comment: Yes, looks like as long as the fieldnames match it shares the column for the promoted field - thanks, a lot simpler than I had feared!

Comment: that tends to work where they are flat, but in the past i have run into issues where the field exists within groups within groups. This is a consideration to be addressed when creating the form template. but i would love to find out if i am just wrong about that limit. Any comments?